# Spark UI is showing negative number of SQL Sessions

Tags: apache-spark, apache-spark-sql, distributed-computing

I deployed Spark-1.5.0 with 3 Nodes and running in Standalone mode. And i am using default spark's thriftserver application for Spark Sql.

But after some normal queries when i see my Spark UI, it showing negative Session number.

[image]

Comment: Sounds like a bug. You should report it to the bug tracker.

Comment: Yes its probably a bug, - i guess this is a running count of those sessions which have been active previously, and decrementing past the 0 count when they finish

Answer (score 0):

Since I faced the same issue, let me confirm too that this is a *bug* of the UI ([Spark UI is showing negative number of sessions](https://issues.apache.org/jira/browse/SPARK-13111)).